# Convert list of named vectors with missing objects to data.frame

Tags: r, type-conversion

There are many examples how to convert a list of named vectors to a `data.frame`, but they assume all that the vector in each list element has the same names. I have the situation, where not all have all named elements. The example:

```
x <- list(
  a = c(id = "one",   name = "Robert", remarks = "none"  ),
  b = c(id = "two",   name = "Edgar"                     ),
  c = c(id = "three", name = "Edward", remarks = "stupid")
)
```

I would now like to have a `data.frame` (without using dplyr), as if the missing remark would be `NA`:

```
x <- list(
  a = c(id = "one",   name = "Robert", remarks = "none"  ),
  b = c(id = "two",   name = "Edgar",  remarks = NA      ),
  c = c(id = "three", name = "Edward", remarks = "stupid")
)

as.data.frame(x)
```

like this

```
             a     b      c
id         one   two  three
name    Robert Edgar Edward
remarks   none  <NA> stupid
```

Is there an easy way, or do I have to roll out my own function (no problem, but if there is a function, I don't have to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```r
cols <- unique(unlist(sapply(x, names)))

as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(x, function(y) setNames(y[cols], cols))))
#>              a     b      c
#> id         one   two  three
#> name    Robert Edgar Edward
#> remarks   none  <NA> stupid
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer this one, as it also uses the `as.data.frame`  functions and therefore slots nicely in the code I have.

Answer (score 1):

Get the unique names, then subset original list. When list doesn't have that item, it returns NA, this will ensure lengths are all same, then we convert to data.frame:

```
xNames <- unique(unlist(sapply(x, names)))

data.frame(lapply(x, "[", xNames))
#              a     b      c
# id         one   two  three
# name    Robert Edgar Edward
# remarks   none  <NA> stupid
```